# Avoid Android VideoView corruption when rotating back to portrait

Tags: android, corruption, android-videoview, screen-rotation

I've managed to write a limited video player able to view a .3gp file from internet. The video will be shown centered full screen, maintaining the video aspect ratio. Also, rotations don't interrupt the video, which keeps playing without problems.

Everything seems fine, but... on my HTC Legend when you rotate back to portrait, the video is corrupted, and instead of showing full screen it is displayed at its native pixel size. But rotating again to landscape works and is shown perfectly. Any ideas why? Unfortunately I don't have more hardware to test this on and I've run out of ideas to test.

You can get the full example source code from https://github.com/gradha/Android-video-stream-rotation. Here are screen captures of me opening the application, rotating to landscape, touching the screen to display the video controls, then rotating back to portrait to see the corruption.
[image: video started ok in portrait]

[image: on landscape the video works fine too]

[image: but now going back to portrait always shows corruption]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the source code at https://github.com/gradha/Android-video-stream-rotation. you added the comment:

> Since we specified in the
>   AndroidManifest.xml that **we want to handle** our own orientation
>   changes, we resize the screen in function of being portrait or
>   landscape.

From the source code AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

So, if you add this attribute to the activity element in the manifest, I would interpret that as the activity will handle all the orientation changes? not you?

From Android Developers

> To declare that your **activity handles** a configuration change, edit the
>   appropriate activity element in your manifest file to include the
>   android:configChanges attribute... [more](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

So you should **not** need to:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

I created a test project to check if this was the case:

Rotating Video Stream Example: https://github.com/TouchBoarder/RotatingVideoStream

My conclusion:
I did not need to overide the "onConfigurationChanged" in the activity to display the video correct in both portrait and landscape, and the video keeps playing on rotation changes.

Feel free to improve and use the code:)

Comment: Your conclusion is wrong: If I remove that method the video still displays video corruption. OTOH your example works on my device, so the culprit is somewhere else. If I find time I'll look for other changes between both projects.

Comment: Marking your answer as correct for the providing the missing link.

Comment: If you are targeting android >= 13, you have to put android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" besides just android:configChanges="orientation"

Comment: your video stream example link is died. please provide the working code. @TouchBoarder

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my whole test case was wrong. Right up until [the commit where I blame the easy videoview example on being wrong](https://github.com/gradha/Android-video-stream-rotation/commit/8a299d2c277811948ef29811595583f950477287) everything was according to the book. However I forgot the `android:configChanges="orientation"` line, and adding this line on top of the previously mentioned commit makes everything work without video corruption.

I'll be marking hsigmond's answer as valid for providing a test example I could compare to and find out the true problem. My whole working around this with custom orientation handlers and a subclass of the VideoView was wrong and incorrectly based on the question [Android VideoView orientation change with buffered video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434027). Not that *that* is wrong, I simply applied it incorrectly (plus other answers there also mentioned the missing `android:configChanges`).