# How to play video in VideoView?

Tags: android, playback, android-videoview

I want to play video in `VideoView`.
When I try to do that I got the following error:

[image]

Here is my source code:

```
package com.video.listitem;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class PlayVideo extends Activity {

     VideoView mVideoView;
     MediaController mc;
     String videourl;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.videoplay);

        try {
             mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
             String videourl = "rtsp://v7.cache4.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQl25yDUbxNXTRMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp";
             mc = new MediaController(this);
             mVideoView.setMediaController(mc);
             mVideoView.requestFocus();
             mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videourl));
             mc.show();
             mVideoView.start();
         } catch (Exception e) {
         //TODO: handle exception
         }  
    }
}
```

Here is my XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:gravity="center">

    <VideoView
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:id="@+id/videoview" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your error log..

Comment: i got like this:      10-10 18:16:14.253: ERROR/PlayerDriver(31): Command PLAYER_PREPARE completed with an error or info PVMFFailure
10-10 18:16:14.253: ERROR/MediaPlayer(5161): error (1, -1)
10-10 18:16:14.263: ERROR/MediaPlayer(5161): Error (1,-1)
10-10 18:16:14.263: DEBUG/VideoView(5161): Error: 1,-1

Comment: you have include internet permission in your manifest?

Comment: yes..i done that but still i am facing problem

Comment: Please post the solution, I am facing the same problem. Thanks

Comment: i have also check this , but facing same problem :( please post the solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play video from url in VideoView \[Android\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40433248/play-video-from-url-in-videoview-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to run app in Device , Video may not run in Emulator...

Comment: yeah i tried it also but facing same problem .. please post the solution :(

Answer (score 1):

Try to add permission to connect to internet !

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
```

Answer (score 1):

see my answere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12736807/546054) in the example code provided. If video is not playing try to re-encode it with a program like [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) and try again. Info on supported video formats: [Android Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this problem may be in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24380224/5366641):

> Returning `false` or not having an `OnErrorListener` at all will cause
>   the `OnCompletionListener` to be called.
>
> So return `true` instead of `false` from the function and no error
>   will be shown, i.e.
>
> ```
> video.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
>
>     @Override
>     public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
>         Log.d("video", "setOnErrorListener ");
>         return true;
>     }
> });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void playVideo() {
            videoView = findViewById(R.id.vid);
 videoView.setVideoPath("rtsp://v7.cache4.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQl25yDUbxNXTRMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp")
            videoView.start();
        }
```

Just call this function in your onCreate() method

Answer (score -3):

May be the url is not correct. Try to play that stream using vlc player. If it is played then we can look into other possible reason

Answer (score -3):

Ok first thing you wanna do is clean up your layout, this is your first problem:

unmesh it first and make the problem viewable:

You should have caught the error which is missing your closing cap after center", just add a ">" ... and that's it. Clean the project and you should see rtsp video. And your Internet Permission as previously stated.